# writing cookie with a domain name

Tags: javascript

Below is the code I am writing to set the cookie with domain name= “.example.com” but this isn’t working.  Any idea what’s wrong with the code? However if I remove the domain name, it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
       alert("Cookie = " + document.cookie);

       var c_value=escape(value);`enter code here`

       var myDate = new Date();

       myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
       document.cookie = c_name +"=" + value + ";expires=" + myDate + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="setCookie('name','value')">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions. It might help ;)

```
cookie_create = function (name,value,days) {
    var expires, date;

    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

expires = date = null;
};

cookie_read = function (name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=",
    ca = document.cookie.split(';'),
    len = ca.length,
    i, c; 

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1); //,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length); //,c.length);
    }

nameEQ = name = ca = i = c = len = null;
return null;
};

cookie_erase = function (name){
    cookie_create(name,"",-1);
name = null;
};
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response, but i can't see any code to set the domain name?

Comment: That's because there isn't domain name :) Cookie is just a big string. You put inside what ever you want and need. Format your string and put it in as value param.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "; path=" + "/") + 
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "; domain=.example.com") +  
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
```